# GUI for bazaar, equivalent of gitk

Tags: user-interface, bazaar

What is a maintained GUI for bzr, perhaps something like gitk for git?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `bzr qlog` from [QBzr](http://bazaar-vcs.org/QBzr). It looks like this:

[alt text http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/9564/qlogpicard.png](http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/9564/qlogpicard.png)

Answer (score 2):

You could try the default GUI, Bazaar Explorer. It is based on QBzr, but can launch Bzr-GTK applets as well.

Answer (score 1):

there's [olive-gtk](http://bazaar-vcs.org/Olive/), which is now part of the [bzr-gtk](http://bazaar-vcs.org/bzr-gtk) package.

it allows you to view/browse history, diff files, etc.